# OSStatus Code -1009, com.apple.LocalAuthentication

Tags: xcode, keychain, xctest, osstatus

I'm trying to test encryption using the iOS keychain.

```
Domain=com.apple.LocalAuthentication Code=-1009 "ACL operation is not allowed: 'od'" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=ACL operation is not allowed: 'od'}
```

This is my test code:

```
func testEncrpytKeychain() {

    let promise = expectation(description: "Unlock")
    let data: Data! = self.sampleData
    let text: String! = self.sampleText
    wait(for: [promise], timeout: 30)
    let chain = Keychain(account: "tester", serviceName: "testing2", access: .whenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly, accessGroup: nil)
    chain.unlockChain { reply, error in
        defer {
            promise.fulfill()
        }
        guard error == nil else {
            // ** FAILS ON THIS LINE WITH OSSTATUS ERROR **
            XCTAssert(false, "Error: \(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }

        guard let cipherData = try? chain.encrypt(data) else {
            XCTAssert(false, "Cipher Data not created")
            return
        }
        XCTAssertNotEqual(cipherData, data)

        guard let clearData = try? chain.decrypt(cipherData) else {
            XCTAssert(false, "Clear Data not decrypted")
            return
        }
        XCTAssertEqual(clearData, data)

        let clearText = String(data: clearData, encoding: .utf8)
        XCTAssertEqual(clearText, text)
    }
}
```

And this is the underlying async `unlockChain` code:

```
// context is a LAContext
func unlockChain(_ callback: @escaping (Bool, Error?) -> Void) {
    var error: NSError? = nil
    guard context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, error: &error) else {
        callback(false, error)
        return
    }

    context.evaluateAccessControl(control, operation: .createItem, localizedReason: "Access your Account") { (reply, error) in
        self.context.evaluateAccessControl(self.control, operation: .useItem, localizedReason: "Access your Account") { (reply, error) in
            self.unlocked = reply
            callback(reply, error)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how the context and control objects are made

```
 init(account: String, serviceName: String = (Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? ""),  access: Accessibility = .whenUnlocked, accessGroup: String? = nil) {
    self.account = account
    self.serviceName = serviceName
    self.accessGroup = accessGroup
    self.access = access
    var error: Unmanaged<CFError>? = nil
    self.control = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                   access.attrValue,
                                                   [.privateKeyUsage],
                                                   &error)
    if let e: Error = error?.takeRetainedValue() {
        Log.error(e)
    }
    self.context = LAContext()
}
```

I can't find a single bit of information about this error:

```
Domain=com.apple.LocalAuthentication Code=-1009
```

the [OSStatus Code site doesn't contain anything for it either](https://www.osstatus.com/search/results?platform=all&framework=all&search=-1009)

any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This looks like you're running it in a unit test.  Does it also fail on the device? It just feels like something that could be a little wonky if it isn't running on a physical device.

Comment: It's running in a unit test on the device.  In addition, I've run it in-app on the device and the error message is the same.

Comment: I've got the same error while trying to sign with the "ecdsa digest" algorithm. Did you find where it was coming from? ```Error Domain=com.apple.LocalAuthentication Code=-1009 "ACL operation is not allowed: 'osgn'" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=ACL operation is not allowed: 'osgn'``` there is no test on my side, and the weirdest is that it's working fine on iOS11 but not on iOS10 :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue by removing the previous private key before creating a new one.

I would guess that on iOS10 (11 was not showing up the error), when you `SecKeyCreateRandomKey(...)` with the same tag/size but not the same access settings, it would just return `true` but use the old one (feels odd but who knows)?

Here is a lazy C function I just made to remove it (just remember to set your `ApplicationPrivateKeyTag`:

```
void deletePrivateKey()
{
    CFStringRef ApplicationPrivateKeyTag = CFSTR("your tag here");

    const void* keys[] = {
        kSecAttrApplicationTag,
        kSecClass,
        kSecAttrKeyClass,
        kSecReturnRef,
    };

    const void* values[] = {
        ApplicationPrivateKeyTag,
        kSecClassKey,
        kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate,
        kCFBooleanTrue,
    };

    CFDictionaryRef params = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, keys, values, (sizeof(keys)/sizeof(void*)), NULL, NULL);

    OSStatus status = SecItemDelete(params);

    if (params) CFRelease(params);
    if (ApplicationPrivateKeyTag) CFRelease(ApplicationPrivateKeyTag);

    if (status == errSecSuccess)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

FWIW: it looks like apple updated [their doc about the Security Framework and the SecureEnclave](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/storing_keys_in_the_secure_enclave?language=objc), it's a bit easier to understand now.